# SUM for specific

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

i am new at this. esp. sql. I need to make SUM from number of purchases, for each product code. Specifing 
SUM by name of productcode is not an option, because of quantity of product codes. Example:

```
productcode     nameofproduct      quantityofpurchase
code1           product1           4
code288         product288         1
code1           product1           2
```

Output would be:

```
code1           product1        6           
code288         product288      1
```

---

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use aggregation:

```
select 
    product_code,
    name_of_product,
    sum(quantity_of_purchase) total_quantity
from mytable
group by product_code, name_of_product
```